# Set Eureka row value programmatically

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to instantiate a FormViewController and set the values for some of the rows.  I tried to access the row using rowByTag but it's returning nil and crashing the app.

```
let formViewController = FormViewController()
formViewController.rowBy(tag: "nameRow").value = "John Smith"
```

I've also tried.

```
let nameRow = formViewController.rowBy(tag: "nameRow") as! NameRow
nameRow.value = "John Smith"
```

Comment: Try few examples from [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/tree/master/Example) to learn the use of `FormViewController`. You can not do the way you tried.

Comment: how did you add that NameRow to form sections?